Linux file access race condition
I expected to see some form of error from OS or at least unreadable data in that text file!
Can someone tell me what is going on here?
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def open_file(metadata):
    with open("text.txt","a") as f:
        s = f"""{metadata} = {time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}\n"""
        for ch in s:
            f.write(ch)
        print(f"writing {s[:-2]}, now sleeping for 10 seconds before closing the file.")
        time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool() as p:
        p.map(open_file, range(50))

I tried to have different processes writing to a single file and expected to get an OS error message or unreadable data in the text file.
here is the output
0 = 2024-06-10 15:30:19
2 = 2024-06-10 15:30:19
4 = 2024-06-10 15:30:19
8 = 2024-06-10 15:30:19
6 = 2024-06-10 15:30:19
12 = 2024-06-10 15:30:19
10 = 2024-06-10 15:30:19
14 = 2024-06-10 15:30:19
1 = 2024-06-10 15:30:29
5 = 2024-06-10 15:30:29
3 = 2024-06-10 15:30:29
9 = 2024-06-10 15:30:29
7 = 2024-06-10 15:30:29
15 = 2024-06-10 15:30:29
11 = 2024-06-10 15:30:29
13 = 2024-06-10 15:30:29
16 = 2024-06-10 15:30:39
18 = 2024-06-10 15:30:39
20 = 2024-06-10 15:30:39
22 = 2024-06-10 15:30:39
28 = 2024-06-10 15:30:39
24 = 2024-06-10 15:30:39
26 = 2024-06-10 15:30:39
30 = 2024-06-10 15:30:39
17 = 2024-06-10 15:30:49
19 = 2024-06-10 15:30:49
23 = 2024-06-10 15:30:49
21 = 2024-06-10 15:30:49
25 = 2024-06-10 15:30:49
29 = 2024-06-10 15:30:49
27 = 2024-06-10 15:30:49
31 = 2024-06-10 15:30:49
32 = 2024-06-10 15:30:59
34 = 2024-06-10 15:30:59
38 = 2024-06-10 15:30:59
36 = 2024-06-10 15:30:59
42 = 2024-06-10 15:30:59
40 = 2024-06-10 15:30:59
44 = 2024-06-10 15:30:59
46 = 2024-06-10 15:30:59
33 = 2024-06-10 15:31:09
37 = 2024-06-10 15:31:09
39 = 2024-06-10 15:31:09
35 = 2024-06-10 15:31:09
43 = 2024-06-10 15:31:09
41 = 2024-06-10 15:31:09
45 = 2024-06-10 15:31:09
47 = 2024-06-10 15:31:09
48 = 2024-06-10 15:31:19
49 = 2024-06-10 15:31:29



What are you getting instead of an error or unreadable data? Just a readable text file?

Yes a readable text file.

My output differs every time I run the program; is this the case for you as well?

It is different each time you run it but it is still readable!

Python buffers file writes, so your attempt to write character-by-character had no effect - each process did exactly one write system call (and the fact that the file is in "a" mode guarantees that those writes appeared at the very end of the file).  If you had flushed the file between each character, then you would likely have got an unreadable mess - but no characters would be missing, they'd just be interleaved with writes from other processes.

You're seeing buffered I/O.
Flush writes after every byte, and you'll see interesting things.
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool


def open_file(metadata):
    with open("text.txt", "a") as f:
        s = f"""{metadata} = {time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}\n"""
        for ch in s:
            f.write(ch)
            f.flush()
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool() as p:
        p.map(open_file, range(50))

has text.txt contain (e.g.)
17 = 2024-06-10 17:36:27
2119  ==  22002244--0066--1100  1177::3366::2277

for me.

Intersting! But still why buffered I/O doesn't mix-up things.

Because (as far as I know) append mode means just that: append to the end of the file, no matter how many things are writing into it. You can't seek an append-mode file, nor read it, either. When the writes are buffered, they'll end up being atomic.

@FarhadMohammadi Also worth noting that you open and close the file 50 times.  Each with statement closes the file before exiting.  If you had one file handle that stayed open the entire time, then some data would likely be overwritten.  Not interleaved chars like akx's answer but entire lines overwriting or clipping each other.

@Ed_ Note that OP's post has time.sleep()s, so the handles do stay open for a while.

@AKX that doesn't change semantics.  Append-mode only preserves data from different file handles.  Multiple processes writing to the same handle can create collisions.  The result partly depends on underlying OS, but I've seen data loss happen in such cases.

There is nothing wrong in the output.

On Linux, a process writing to a file does not lock the file in any way.

Appending to a file guarantees that no data is overwritten.

The output is buffered, the actual OS file writes are small in size and therefore atomic, i.e. each line is written from beginning to the end.


